# Send JSON from Flask to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, flask, leaflet

I have a problem with send data from Flask to JavaScript. I have the informations whitch i get from the database and I add this data to the dictionary. Now I want to have JSON object in JavaScript for dispaly this information on a map. I use `JSON.parse` in JavaScript but it doesnt work.

Code in route.py

```
@app.route('/mapaa',methods=['GET','POST'])
def mapa():
    slownik = {}
    if 'event_form' in request.form:
        name = request.form['name_event']
        all_data = Event.query.filter_by(name=name).all()
        for row in all_data:
            slownik.update({'id':row.id})
            slownik.update({'date_st':row.date_start})
            slownik.update({'date_end':row.date_end})
            slownik.update({'type':row.type})
            slownik.update({'name':row.name})
            slownik.update({'len_route':row.len_route})
            slownik.update({'route':row.route})
    return render_template('mapaa.html', title='Mapa',data=slownik)
```

In JavaScript mapa.js:

```
 var parsed = JSON.parse('{{data | tojson}}');
 console.log(data)
```

But it return:

```
VM475:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

What I am doing wrong ? I will add that `date_end` and `date_start` are datatime type. I tried to `jsonify` this dictionary too but it also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this within your template `mappa.html` script`tag to parse the`json `using [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#tojson) filter:

```
<script>
    var parsed = {{ data | tojson | safe}};

    console.log(parsed)
</script>
```

Comment: When i used `{{data | tojson}};` without `'  '` this return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: Use the above snippet, you don't need to parse the json, `{{ data | tojson| safe}}` will parse the json to `parsed` variable

Comment: I dont understand why it work in `mapaa.html` but in `mapa.js` not working ?

Comment: You can import the js file in the template and pass the value to the JS module from the templates. I guess this will solve your issue.